# Why does my OpenSSL C++ code create binary encryption output?

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a file using AES from OpenSSL and then write the output to a file. But I'm getting messy outputs, sometimes decipherable and sometimes not.

The main code is based from here: https://github.com/shanet/Crypto-Example/blob/master/crypto-example.cpp

Here's the code:

```
int Crypt::__aesEncrypt(const unsigned char *msg, size_t msgLen, unsigned char **encMsg) {
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *aesEncryptCtx = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*)malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(aesEncryptCtx);

unsigned char *aesKey = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);
unsigned char *aesIV = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);

unsigned char *aesPass = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);
unsigned char *aesSalt = (unsigned char*)malloc(8);

if(RAND_bytes(aesPass, AES_KEYLEN/8) == 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(RAND_bytes(aesSalt, 8) == 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), aesSalt, aesPass, AES_KEYLEN/8, AES_ROUNDS, aesKey, aesIV) == 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

strncpy((char*)aesKey, (const char*)"B374A26A71490437AA024E4FADD5B4AA", AES_KEYLEN/8);
strncpy((char*)aesIV, (const char*)"7E892875A52C59A3B588306B13C31FBD", AES_KEYLEN/16);

size_t blockLen = 0;
size_t encMsgLen = 0;

*encMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(msgLen + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
if(encMsg == NULL) return FAILURE;

if(!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(aesEncryptCtx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, aesKey, aesIV)) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(aesEncryptCtx, *encMsg, (int*)&blockLen, (unsigned char*)msg, msgLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}
encMsgLen += blockLen;

if(!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(aesEncryptCtx, *encMsg + encMsgLen, (int*)&blockLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(aesEncryptCtx);
free(aesEncryptCtx);

free(aesKey);
free(aesIV);

return encMsgLen + blockLen;
```

}

Im calling like this:

```
unsigned char *encMsg = NULL;
    __aesEncrypt((const unsigned char*)decrypted_string.c_str(), decrypted_string.size(), &encMsg);

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << encMsg;
    //write ss to file...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you want that encryption to be readable hex text (like Base64 encoded or BinHex)? You'll have to do that yourself on the enrypted message block prior to writing it to your text stream. Also, it looks like you want to use the key as *bytes*, yet you're passing a ascii key *string*. I've not used OpenSSL for sometime now, but I don't think it will just translate it for you before the encryption.

Comment: I think there's no difference for me, thanks.

Comment: I think you missed my point. The text stream, via the `operator <<` is expecting *characters*. That isn't what you're giving it.

Comment: Oh, yes, thats true. Sorry. I can change some flag to do it?

Comment: Err, isn't it *supposed* to 'create binary encryption output'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm actually the author of the example you've based your code off of. As WhozCraig pointed out in the comments above, you are using a `stringstream` to write the encrypted message to a file. The problem with this is that **encrypted messages are not regular ASCII strings**. They are binary data (values greater than 127, hence the need for an unsigned char array) and binary data cannot be treated the same as ASCII strings.

I'm not much of a C++ person, so I would write the data to a file the C way with `fwrite`, but if you want to do it the C++ way, I think you're looking for `ifstream` rather than `stringstream`.

Side note, I'm betting this is just for debugging, but I'll point it out anyway just to make sure: Hardcoding your AES key and IV (`strncpy((char*)aesKey, (const char*)"B374A26A71490437AA024E4FADD5B4AA", AES_KEYLEN/8)`) completely defeats the purpose of encryption. If you want to avoid the PBKDF (`EVP_BytesToKey`) you can just use `RAND_Bytes` to get random data for your AES key.

Comment: +1. Using a formatted string stream with hex encoding (effectively bin hex) is one option for text writing. Another is using the built-in Base64 encoder for OpenSSL. I would probably use the latter, as your decryption process can use the same API set for decoding to bytes before decrypting (and as I said, its been awhile, but I would not be at-all-surprised if OpenSSL has an option for doing both in a single step *somewhere* in their API).

Comment: @WhozCraig Good idea with the base64. I'll add that to my example since I get questions about encrypted messages being binary data all the time.

Comment: That'd be good. the only other thing I'd do if plausible on your side is "std-lib-reroll" the sample to use `std:vector<>` and `std::string` liberally, eliminating near-to-or-all of those C-lib memory management functions. the code will be significantly simplified in doing so. If I get the time, I'll do it on an off-day and drop a link in this message. Wishing you all the best.